# Report error at source of __newindex call rather than inside __newindex function

Tags: error-handling, lua

I have a metatable with the following `__newindex` function:

```
__newindex = function(t, key, value)
  set_value(t.sprite_number, key, value)
end
```

This lets me allow users to set "properties" on my lua objects (there's a corresponding `__index` function, but it's not really relevant).

`set_value` is a C function. If you try to set the wrong type on a "property," say setting a string value on an integer property, the C code does

```
luaL_error (l, "property must be a number");
```

This works fine, except the error reported from lua is

```
[string "-- init.lua..."]:10: property must be a number
```

Which is referring to the set_value function call in my __newindex function. This isn't very helpful. I'd like the error to instead point to the place where the wrong value was set, i.e. in the spot where you do

```
object.property = "expects integer"
```

Can I accomplish this somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [error](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-error) function and give the `level` parameter:

```
__newindex = function(t, key, value)
  local ok, err = pcall(set_value, t.sprite_number, key, value)
  -- level 2 means that the error will be signaled on 2nd stack frame,
  -- that is the line at which the key has been set
  if not ok then error(err, 2) end
end
```